# In a tcl script how can i use puts to write a string to the console and to a file at the same time?

Tags: tcl, tclsh

```
# Prints the string in a file
puts $chan stderr "$timestamp - Running test: $test"

# Prints the string on a console
puts "$timestamp - Running test: $test"
```

Is there a way I can send the output of puts to the screen and to a log file at the same time? Currently I have both the above two lines one after the other in my script to achieve this.

Or is there any other solution in tcl ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following proc instead of `puts`:

```
proc multiputs {args} {
    if { [llength $args] == 0 } {
        error "Usage: multiputs ?channel ...? string"
    } elseif { [llength $args] == 1 } {
        set channels stdout
    } else {
        set channels [lrange $args 0 end-1]
    }
    set str [lindex $args end]
    foreach ch $channels {
        puts $ch $str
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
# print on stdout only
multiputs "1"

# print on stderr only
multiputs stderr "2"

set brieflog [open brief.log w]
set fulllog [open detailed.log w]
# print on stdout and in the log files
multiputs stdout $brieflog $fulllog "3"
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't something I've used extensively, but it seems to work (Tcl 8.6+ only):

You need the channel transform `tcl::transform::observe` package:

```
package require tcl::transform::observe
```

Open a log file for writing and set buffering to none:

```
set f [open log.txt w]
chan configure $f -buffering none
```

Register `stdout` as a receiver:

```
set c [::tcl::transform::observe $f stdout {}]
```

Anything written to the channel `$c` will now go to both the log file and `stdout`.

```
puts $c foobar
```

Note that it would seem to make more sense to have the channel transformation on top of `stdout`, with the channel to the log file as receiver, but I haven't been able to make that work.

Documentation:
[chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[tcl::transform::observe (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/virtchannel_transform/observe.html)